how to combine gatling reports from multiple machines
I have a k8s job that launch multiple pods with gatling load test instance written on java .
After the pods completed I want to collect gatling results and merge it into one html file.
I'm using the

io.gatling.highcharts:gatling-charts-highcharts:3.12.0 dependency
io.gatling:gatling-maven-plugin:4.9.6

I found info about some gatling.sh script that was allows to merge reports but now no any data about the file in the official gatling docs.
No any info about how to combine reports in the official gatling documentation.
What can I do to combine results using my environment?

They used to have a section on scaling out with the open source version. Not sure the method suggested there will still work.

Until recently it was very easy, just put all simulation log files into your Maven target directory, like target/gatling/mysimulation and then run mvn gatling:test -Dgatling.reportsOnly=mysimulation.
Gatling used to combine the reports into one. With Gatling 3.12 this doesn't seem to work anymore, 3.11.5 still works for me. Was about to search for this issue as I upgraded to recent version. Looks like there is no bug report open so.
So for now you might want to stick with an old version...
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.gatling.highcharts</groupId>
    <artifactId>gatling-charts-highcharts</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.5</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

...OR what also seems to work for me right now, just concatenate all you simulation.log files into one. This single combined log files must be named simulation.log to be found now.
The resulting report index.htm seems to be identical for both, except for version and date information:


created a ticket with minimal example now: https://github.com/gatling/gatling/issues/4591

they won't bring it back I guess, but forking the repo and reverting https://github.com/gatling/gatling/commit/2fb207dabf97a17e87d705991ca2145b6bd2b85a might work as well for you
